# iBeacon app behave differently on 2 different iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Another Beacon question.

I purchase a $10 beacon from Amazon for testing and experimental purpose.
I developed an app in iOS swift  and based on the distance, It displays a message on the screen

```
func updateDistance(distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { [unowned self] in
        switch distance {
        case .Unknown:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "No Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Far:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Weak Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Near:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Medium Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Immediate:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Strong Beacon Signal Detected"
        }
    }
}
```

I am running the same app on 2 different iPhones. one is iphone 6 software version 8.4.1 and the other is iPhone 5S software version 8.4.1.

Both iphones are at the same distance gives me 2 different readings. For example when iPhone6 shows "Strong Beacon Signal Detected" iphone 5s shows medium Signal". Also when iphone 5S  shows "No Beacon Signal Detected" iPhone 6 still shows "Weak signal for another 15 to 20 feet.
Also iPhone 5s sometimes looses signal for a sec or so.

So my question is shouldn't both phones behave the same?

Answer (score 2):

The distance value for iBeacons is relative, and so variable as to be pretty much useless. It uses radio signal strength to estimate distance to the beacon, and radio signal strength is subject to an almost limitless number of variables.

One of those variables will be the gain of the antenna on the phone you are using to measure the signal. I wouldn't expect 2 recent generation phones to give results as radically different as you report though.

It sounds like the bluetooth receiver on your 5s may be "dodgy".

Are you using them both "naked"? (Not in a case) and holding them by the corners? Thinks like cases and how you hold the phone can affect signal strength, as can interference from things like fluorescent lights and signal blockage and echoes from nearby objects.

Comment: This is correct.  Phones do vary from one model to the next.  The problem is especially extreme on Android devices.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. In all condition iPhone 6 reports better result. Tomorrow I'll test with iPhone 4s to see what kind of result I get.

Comment: iPhone 4S and iPhone 5S are very much the same. iPhone 6 gave the best result.
One other question is how one can determine the quality of beacon?
also is it possible to shorten the range? For example when phone is more than 10 feet to 40 feet away from the beacon I am getting weak signal. I want to find out a way to know I am out of the zone if I am more  than 15 feet away from the beacon. is there a API for  that?

Comment: The iBeacon standard has a setting for beacon transmitters called RSSI (received signal strength indicator) that lets you adjust for devices of different output powers. It lets you specify the signal strength of your transmitter from 1 meter and causes the receiver to calibrate its distance estimates accordingly. You can use the RSSI setting to lie and increase or decrease the reported distance.

Comment: There are also some beacon transmitters that actually let you adjust the real broadcast power of the device up or down. If memory serves Gimbal beacons are one of the brands that have this ability, but I'm not at my development Mac where I have that information so I can't easily verify.